# Add perfmon counter from remote machine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon

Have a strange issue where one user on Windows 2008 Server R2 can add performance counters from a different server (same OS) but a second user can't because

> cannot connect to remote machine.

Both users are local administrators on the local machine where perfmon is being used to add the counters

There must be something different between the users but I've checked all group memberships and permissions etc.

Comment: Are both users on the same network? Could they be traversing different firewalls?

Comment: So lets call the servers A and B, both users login into A and one can perfmon against B but the other can't, correct? if so are both users in the remote servers administrators group and or the local group "performance monitor group"?

Comment: Same network, same firewalls.

Comment: Both users have identical remote machine and local machine group memberships

Comment: can both users from server A run at an elevated command prompt "wmic /node:B os"?

Comment: Do both users have the same password?